# How to use svg clipping mask to animate circles?

Tags: animation, svg, mask, slick.js, clip-path

I want to create circles inside lenses that move inside lenses when slick slider transform.
What's the correct way to do it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYeO8.jpg)

I used svg and clip-path with mask but the mask doesn't work as expected!

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 716.2093 848.146">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="circle-clippath">
      <circle cx="162.5532" cy="146.7213" r="96.4158" style="fill: url(#radial-gradient-2);"/>
    </clippath>
    <mask id="circle-mask">
      <circle cx="162.5532" cy="146.7213" r="96.4158" style="fill:#fff"/>
    </mask>
 </defs>
 lens svg code ....
 <g clip-path="url(#circle-clippath)"> 
   <circle cx="162.7743" cy="148.0393" r="136.4791" style="fill: #f36f31;" mask="url(#circle-mask)">
 </g>
</svg>
``
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: "when slick slider transform" Can you explain what that means? So, should the circle move around inside the "lenses" and how?